# adding rows to a TableLayout programmatically issue

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to add row to a TableLayout programmatically, because the number of rows is variable depending on a List that I retreive from DB ..

I'm facing this problem

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.TableRow$LayoutParams
            at android.widget.TableRow.mapIndexAndColumns(TableRow.java:164)
            at android.widget.TableRow.getVirtualChildCount(TableRow.java:149)
            at android.widget.TableRow.getColumnsWidths(TableRow.java:289)
            at android.widget.TableLayout.findLargestCells(TableLayout.java:508)
            at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:473)
            at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:439)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my code, I'm trying to display every element in the List in a row with 3 columns

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.supports);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


        for(Support s : supports){
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView nom = new TextView(getActivity());
            nom.setText(s.getNom());
            nom.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(nom);

            TextView date = new TextView(getActivity());
            nom.setText(sdf.format(s.getDateSupport()));
            nom.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(date);

            TextView pgCol = new TextView(getActivity());
            nom.setText(s.getPgCol());
            nom.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(pgCol);

            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a cast problem.

`TableLayout.LayoutParams` is different from `TableRow.LayoutParams`

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

should be:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

And so on with your other controls.

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.supports);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


        for(Support s : supports){
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView nom = new TextView(getActivity());
            nom.setText(s.getNom());
            nom.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(nom);

            TextView date = new TextView(getActivity());
            nom.setText(sdf.format(s.getDateSupport()));
            nom.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(date);

            TextView pgCol = new TextView(getActivity());
            nom.setText(s.getPgCol());
            nom.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(pgCol);

            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
```